# How to achieve that a task just run on one instance with spring-boot microservice architecture

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

Have one service named AccountService.5 instances are needed to support the traffic.all these instances run in docker container.Now I need to run a schedule task.**this task should only run on a single AccountService instance.but not all the five instances.which one is not important**

My question is how to configure to achieve this.Can eureka do this?and zookeeper seems have the ability to manage the cluster.Do I need to register the AccountService into Zookeeper?

Hope someone can share experience with me

Comment: Locking functionality should implemented with zookeeper
https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a shared data store like Redis or, if you're already using a DB, a table in the DB, to have a task lock. The first instance to come up can grab the lock, run the task, and release the lock.

Comment: In this way,may be there is no need  to lock db.Just query a result from DB,if one instance got it,and then update it.So the status changed,other instances would not excute task as the query result is not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

1. Include **spring-cloud-task** in your dependency (which is suitable for scheduled tasks).
2. Then enable this property - **spring.cloud.task.single-instance-enabled=true**
3. Add **Spring Integration** dependencies. Copy/paste from here - https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-task/docs/current/reference/#features-single-instance-enabled

Note:
Locks are created and stored under TASK_LOCK table. Make sure its clean, otherwise you will have problems restarting.

Answer (score -2):

Use Spring Based task scheduling `@Schedule`

For more [click here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks)